# Comparing timedelta with dt.time in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I've got a pandas series called `df['inc_cr_date']` that has dates in format `2017-10-27 08:00:26.808`.

I would like to compare if date and hour of this column is higher than 18:30. The problem is that if I use the below code:

```
#All the condtions can be reduced to one mask and result 
days_one = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday']
days_two = days_one + ['Friday']

# Returns a boolean mask 
m1 = df['inc_cr_date_day'].isin(days_one) & (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour > 18 ) & (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute > 30)
m2 = df['inc_cr_date_day'].isin(days_two) & (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour < 9 ) & (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute < 30)

# Repeated result can be stored in one variable 
r1 = (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes')
r2 = (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('0 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes')


df['inc_cr_date_adjusted'] = np.select([
                          m1, m2,      
                          (df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Saturday'),
                          (df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Sunday'),
                          ((df['inc_cr_date_day'] == 'Friday')& (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour > 18 ) & df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute > 30),
                          ],
                          [r1, r2,
                          (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('2 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),
                          (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('1 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes'),                           
                          (df['inc_cr_date']+pd.Timedelta('3 days')).dt.normalize() + pd.Timedelta('9 Hours 30 Minutes')
                          ],
                          df['inc_cr_date'])
```

this will get me ambiguity results as first condition might be true but second could not be. How could I compare the ['inc_cr_date'] column with 18:30 and NOT with minutes and hour separated?

I've tried to use also **pandas.DataFrame.between_time** as below:

```
start = datetime.time(18,30,0)
end = datetime.time(23,59,0)

df['inc_cr_date'].between_time(start, end) )
```

But getting the error:

```
TypeError: Index must be DatetimeIndex
```

Even if I do:

```
df['inc_cr_date'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['inc_cr_date'])
```

Dataframe is like below:

```
  inc_cr_date                  inc_cr_date_day       
0 2017-10-26 21:59:28.075      Thursday 2017-10-27   
1 2017-10-21 16:49:58.722      Saturday 2017-10-23   
2 2017-10-11 09:30:05.258      Wednesday 2017-10-11
```

Output should be like:

```
  inc_cr_date                  inc_cr_date_day        inc_cr_date_adjusted
0 2017-10-26 21:20:28.075      Thursday 2017-10-27    09:30:00.000
1 2017-10-21 16:49:58.722      Saturday 2017-10-23    09:30:00.000
2 2017-10-11 09:30:05.258      Wednesday 2017-10-11   09:30:05.258
```

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: It would be the best if you could show us an example of input and desired output.

Comment: thanks. just updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
df['timeFlag'] = df['inc_cr_date'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.time() > datetime.time(18, 30, 0) else 0)
```

In your example, you can change these lines:

```
# Returns a boolean mask 
m1 = df['inc_cr_date_day'].isin(days_one) & (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour > 18 ) & (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute > 30)
m2 = df['inc_cr_date_day'].isin(days_two) & (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.hour < 9 ) & (df['inc_cr_date'].dt.minute < 30)
```

to:

```
# Returns a boolean mask 
m1 = df['inc_cr_date_day'].isin(days_one) & (df['inc_cr_date'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.time() > datetime.time(18, 30,0) else 0))
m2 = df['inc_cr_date_day'].isin(days_two) & (df['inc_cr_date'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x.time() > datetime.time(18, 30,0) else 0))
```

Comment: Saw your edit just now; you can adjust the logic to change the time if the condition is met. But, in essence, you can use this logic to check if your time field is between certain times.

Comment: humm, not sure if understand :/